# xml and xslt error

Tags: xml, xslt

i need to modify the XSL file such that the price of the cds which are on promotion is displayed in red color.

here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <cd promotion="Yes">
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>110</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd promotion="No">
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>99</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
    <cd promotion="Yes">
        <title>Greatest Hits</title>
        <artist>Dolly Parton</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>RCA</company>
        <price>75</price>
        <year>1982</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

here is my xsl file. i tried to use choose and when but its not working.I've commented that part.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
            <!--<xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when>
                    <td bgcolor="#ff00ff"><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                          <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>!-->
            <td><xsl:value-of select="year"/></td>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Where is the question? I don't see one. You forgot to provide the wanted output from the transformation, too. In its current state this can hardly be called a question. Please, edit and provide the important, missing information.

Comment: Also, if you have a specific question about an error, like the title implies, you should post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to use an `xsl:apply-templates` and use a template to match `price` elements that have a parent with the attribute `promotional="Yes"`.

Just change the `td` for price to:

```
<td><xsl:apply-templates select="price"/></td>
```

and add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="price[../@promotion='Yes']">
    <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">#ff00ff</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```